# Is Id required attribute for JSF 2 tags?

Tags: java, jsf

Is id required for all JSF 2 tags, for example:

```
<h:outputLabel value=" Variable label:" />
<h:outputText value="#{bean.varialbe}" />
```

Which renders to:
    Variable label: Variable

As such it does renders as expected, but can I run into trouble leaving the ID attribute out? Should I do

```
<h:outputLabel id ="myId" value=" Variable label:" />
<h:outputText id ="myVariableId" value="#{bean.varialbe}" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `id` attribute is optional, at least in the core controls. You might wish to use it if you were using (for example) the `outputLabel`'s `for` attribute or referring to the resultant DOM elements using client identifiers in JavaScript.